# route a word document

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, routing

I heard about the routing feature available in micro soft products (word ,doc) .through which we can route a document in MS outlook.I have no idea how to initiate it.Can some one please tell me the procedure for the same

Comment: .​.​. W​h​a​t​?

Comment: explain what you mean by "routing"

Comment: never mind ,i got what i was looking for. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.towson.edu/adminfinance/ots/training/documentation/Word%202003/Word_Routing_Documents.pdf

Comment: It is called routing in the document, but I guess it simply is sending the doc to multiple users...

Comment: yes that is what it does,and that itself was the question.
This helps a lot a document review.Where in one person can re send to the second one after he is done with his review comments